# Which Unity version should I use?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

So I ask you for a unity version **(specified version number)** that is tested and won't cause me issues in the future, and at least supports the **Third Person Character Control Starter Asset**.

Some of the versions I tried:

**unity 2021.3.3** takes too much time to build (1 hour minimum) especially mobile build, "Your device is weak", I never had this issue with older versions, same project, same assets, takes less time.

**unity 2020** and before, many of the assets I need are not supported.

**unity 2019** manually setup android build (please kill me) + won't work at the end.

**unity 2021.3.16**, newly created URP projects by default are bugged with the issue (Burst Compile Error) and I can't add the URP package to an existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check release notes from each build at this [site](https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive) if you think an older version will suit you better, you have pre-releases as well on the hub or website but those might cause you trouble in future since they can change substantially until they are official releases.

Although It is strongly recommended that you install a LTS version due to support, go figure.

Each issue you face its either your fault, and you can solve it with a search on the topic, or its a bug and its either been fixed on a later build, pending resolution ([there's plenty](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/)) or you could create a [bug report](https://unity.com/releases/editor/qa/bug-reporting).

This is not my place entirely since I only use Unity but I hear **Godot** is light weight and could fit you better.

Comment: Much appreciated. I don't usually ask such questions, but I am so frustrated. I did check the release notes, but those bugs am facing are so random and unknown, I found most of them in unity answers with months old sessions but no answer, or usual steps that usually solve problems, non help. But still thanks. Would you recommend any version ? (Not gonna blame you for anything lol ... And feel free to tell np)

Comment: Honestly I use the latest LTS before I start a "main" project, currently I have 2021.3.16f1 
I would only download a new if I found a bug that was solved, a new relevant feature or if performance got noticeable better in a later version. Although I also dabble sometimes with pre releases for the same reasons, ain't for anything serious, just to grasp what's to come like DOTs in the 2022 versions. If you wanna keep Unity, clean your pc and download the latest LTS and try making simple projects, there's no lighter version of Unity AFAIK, but there are lighter projects.

Comment: oh ok you are using the 2021.3.16f1, you see, this is the last version I downloaded, and I did through unity hub, didn't change anything here or there, and so as I mentioned before, newly created URP projects have an issue (Burst compile error), you didn't face such a problem or know about such a thing?, if not then as you said, I might need to clean every thing and start over. And I don't need a light version of unity, I just ment that it takes too long to download on version cuz of the limit of my internet. anyway thanks for keeping up.

Comment: I dont have burst compilation errors. Try making a fresh question regarding your burst compile error, i think i had it once but was long time ago and was due to DOTs packages. You can link it here i will try to help, but i need more information

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, I found the problem in a different unity form, apparently the (Burst 1.8.2) package is causing the problem, a contradiction between this and the ML Agents package, unity 2021.3.16f1 URP version is depending on burst 1.8.2, so downgrading is not an option (which might solve the problem), and apparently it's a known issue, will be waiting for the Burst 1.8.3 update, but you see, that's the kind of bugs you don't know about until you face, feel free to check the form : https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-after-update-to-unity-2021-3-16f1-lts.1374864/ . Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately theres not much we can do regarding built in features with bugs pending resolve but i am glad you figured out what the issue was. Now you can either change the render pipeline or wait for that update where they fix the issue. Good luck